# Rolling back changes in an mdb file

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I have an old mdb file used by a old vb6 app running on a client's Windows XP laptop. It appears that a bug in the app has deleted a bunch of data in a table in the mdb file. Any way to roll back stuff in access or programmatically? I'm wondering if there's any information stored in the .ldb file or the .mdb file somewhere.  The .mdb file is twice as big as another .mdb file with the same database structure that has more data.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that no. Don't they have a backup? File growth in a .mdb that is in use is normal, it doesn't say anything about how much actual data is in there.

Answer (score 1):

The answer I'm afraid is no. You would have to revert to a backup.

The larger mdb file doesn't contain any extra data - if you run a compact and repair on this larger file it will reduce to the size of the smaller one.